# How to reset the oil life percentage in my Honda car

Tags: honda, oil

My Honda car showed oil life of 15%. I changed the oil, but the oil life indicator is still at 15%. How do I reset the oil life indicator on my Honda automobile?

Comment: Do you have a question or would you simply like to share? The oil life monitor on your vehicle probably does not directly measure the remaining oil life, but simply counts down from 100 based on data like miles traveled & engine revolutions. The oil life monitor will need to be reset to restore the remaining oil life to 100%. The procedure for this depends on the model & year of your vehicle. If you specify which car you drive we might be able to help you with that.

Comment: Please edit your post with more details. We would like to see Year/Make/Model and a direct question. As-is, this isn't a question and might get flagged for closure.

Comment: As @HariGanti  said, you need to include year and model. These are critical to properly answering your question. I have flagged it as "too broad" since you have not updated these details yet. Please do so rapidly so that we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

This will work for most 2006 - 2011 Honda automobiles:

1. Turn the key to the "on" position (be sure to not start the vehicle)
2. Press the Select/Reset knob used to access the odometer and trip
   readings until it displays the oil life percentage
3. Press and hold the knob until the oil life percentage begins to
   blink
4. Release the knob
5. Depress the knob again until the oil life percentage resets to 100%

You did not specify what model and year, so if this doesn't work, you should check your owner's manual for specific instructions.

Comment: A variation on that is, if it comes up with a flashing menu twist the knob to select the upper option and then press the button again.

Comment: For a 2010 Honda Fit, the procedure is as CharlieRB says, but in the manual there's additional detail that is useful: for step 3, you hold the knob for about 10 seconds; for step 5, you press and hold again, this time for about 5 seconds.